# Hello, how can i add another user login pass to my code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to add another user and I am experimenting with this code showed all around the internet.

So I tried this example below,  it works fine, but how could I add another user, let's say for a guest?

is it possible? with like a conditional?

I am just trying to learn more about js and how I can solve this type of simple thing.

```
   methods: {
        login() {
            if(this.input.username == "admin1" && this.input.password == "pass1") {
                this.$store.commit("setAuthentication", true);
                this.$router.replace({ name: "secure" });
            } else {
                console.log("The username and / or password is incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: See [Logical OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR), e.g. `(a && b) || (x && y)`

Comment: I understand that this is just for learning purposes, but for future reference: don't **ever** implement authentication on the client side.

Comment: awesome I knew maybe the logical operator was gonna work on this one...  Thanks! yeah i just like this insecure stuff for prototypes

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen is there a good reference for doing this on the server-side? i am not using nuxt on this Vue app but I am running express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use Below Code:

```
 methods: {
        login() {
            if(this.input.username == "admin1" && this.input.password == "pass1") {
                this.$store.commit("setAuthentication", true);
                this.$router.replace({ name: "secure" });
            } else if (this.input.username == "guest" && this.input.password == "guest1") {
            //  block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is true
            }else {
                console.log("The username and / or password is incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
```